# Exposing a Navigation as a different type in EF Core 6.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm using EF Core 6.0 and wondered if, given the simplified example,the following is possible to *expose/configure* a Navigation as a different type? And if so how?

Exposing as a different type (i.e. `ISomeChildInterface` instead of `SomeChild`) is desirable in my DDD entities, as I want `ParentClass.Children[0].FirstName` etc to be accessible (from my mediator handlers) but not `ParentClass.Children[0].SomeMethod()` in order to protect my businessrules/invariants within the `ParentClass.CallSomeChildMethod()`.

Also notice how I am currently using `.AutoInclude()` and `.HasQueryFilter()` if that makes a difference.

when I try creating a migration I get an error of *Navigation 'SomeParent.Children' was not found. Please add the navigation to the entity type before configuring it.*

```
    public interface ISomeChildInterface
    {
        Guid Id { get; }
        string FirstName { get; }
        string LastName { get; }
    }

    public class SomeChildClass : ISomeChildInterface
    {
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }

        public string FirstName { get; private set; } = null!;

        public string LastName { get; private set; } = null!;

        //parameterless constructor required by EF Core
        private SomeChildClass()
        {

        }

        //private constructor
        private SomeChildClass(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }

        //Static factory create method
        public static SomeChildClass Create(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            return new SomeChildClass(firstName, lastName);
        }

        public void SomeMethod()
        {

        }
    }

    public class ParentClass
    {
        private readonly List<SomeChildClass> _children = new();

        public IReadOnlyCollection<ISomeChildInterface> Children => _children.AsReadOnly();

        public void AddChild(SomeChildClass someChild)
        {
           _children.Add(someChild);
        }

        public void CallSomeChildMethod(Guid childId)
        {
           // Some business rules etc 
           _children.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id => childId).SomeMethod();
        }
    }

    public class SomeContext : IdentityContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // ... snip ...
            _ = modelBuilder.Entity<ParentClass>(entity =>
            {
               _ = entity.Navigation(x => x.Children).AutoInclude().HasField("_children").UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

              //_ = entity.HasQueryFilter(e => UserRoles.Any(x => x.UserId == CurrentUserId && x.RoleId == e.RoleId));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `ParentClass.Children` can't be a navigation property, but you can make the navigation property private.  eg

```
builder.Entity<ParentClass>().HasMany("_children").WithOne();
```

But you won't be able to use `ParentClass.Children` in queries translated to SQL.